# What is the maximum value for system.d MemoryMax

Tags: systemd

In system.d unit we can set the value of `MemoryMax` in bytes.

I know that I can also add the suffix "G" to indicate gigabytes, or "M" for megabytess.

But I was wondering specifically about the length of the value that goes there.
Can I enter something like `512000000` bytes to indicate 512MB or is it too many characters?

Answer (score 0):

The [manual](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#MemoryMax=bytes) says:

> **MemoryMax=bytes**.
> Specify the absolute limit on memory usage of the executed processes in this unit. If memory usage cannot be contained under the limit, out-of-memory killer is invoked inside the unit. It is recommended to use `MemoryHigh=` as the main control mechanism and use `MemoryMax=` as the last line of defense.
>
> Takes a memory size in bytes. If the value is suffixed with `K`, `M`, `G` or `T`, the specified memory size is parsed as Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes, or Terabytes (with the base 1024), respectively. Alternatively, a percentage value may be specified, which is taken relative to the installed physical memory on the system. If assigned the special value "`infinity`", no memory limit is applied.

So yes, you can enter the value in bytes and using a suffix is not required.

In practice the size of the integer you enter there can be as large as the actual amount of memory your system supports or larger even.

Comment: Are you sure there is no limit on the amount of characters enters? Would I be able to enter there 10000000000000000000 ? 
I just noticed that entering it in bytes, caused memory crashed while entering with a "G" worked fine. So I guessed there's like a limit on the integer or something